# How to select the latest dateTime of every month?

Tags: c#, list, sorting, datetime

I have to implement an algorithm who receive a list of DateTime and its recovers the latest DateTime of every month and i don't know how to do it.
Example:

```
29/06/2016 -> Lastest date of june
27/06/2016
05/05/2016 -> Lastest date of may
15/04/2016 -> Lastest date of april
13/04/2016
...
```

Expected result

```
29/06/2016
05/05/2016
15/04/2016
```

Comment: I would calculate how much days each month has, and then check for every month which is the latest date.

Comment: group the DateTimes by year/month and select max from each group

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you aske is the maximum date per month from a list of dates. You can get that with LINQ by using `GroupBy` and `Max`, eg:

```
 var maxDatesPerMonth=from date in dates
                      group date by new {date.Year,date.Month} into months
                      select months.Max();
```

or

```
var maxDatesPerMonth=dates.GroupBy(date=>new {date.Year,date.Month})
                          .Select(months=>months.Max());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dateTimes = new[]
        {

            new DateTime(2016, 06, 29 ),
            new DateTime(2016, 06, 27 ),
            new DateTime(2016, 05, 05 ),
            new DateTime(2016, 04, 15 ),
            new DateTime(2016, 04, 13 )
        };

        var years = dateTimes.GroupBy(x => x.Year).OrderByDescending(x => x.Key);

        foreach (IGrouping<int, DateTime> grouping in years)
        {
            var months = grouping.GroupBy(x => x.Month);

            foreach (IGrouping<int, DateTime> month in months)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(month.First());
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

This output the following...

```
29/06/2016 00:00:00
05/05/2016 00:00:00
15/04/2016 00:00:00
```

Comment: Its a bit rough - don't really have time to optimise it but it should work. Once you get the idea you can streamline it as you see fit.

Comment: It is already ordered by the group-by statement - I only need to pick out the first one because it is exactly the same as MAX. As I said above - this works, but is not optimised. Please explain why you have a problem with code that works?

Comment: Because it uses a lot of extra code and lines, is harder to understand, there *is* a better alternative, and the rows are *not* ordered. You had to force the ordering. `Max` doesn't require any ordering, so this code is slower too

Comment: It is ordered. This solution works. Run the program and see for yourself. If you have a better suggestion, post an answer. Your comments are not constructive. The code works and fulfills the OP's request. As with nearly every coding problem, your way of solving a problem isn't the only way - if you can solve the problem using less lines of code then well done you.

Comment: I already pointed out the many problems with this code. LINQ already provides a much simpler answer, which I did post. In fact, I hadn't noticed you used *two* groupings instead of one. Just because something works doesn't mean its good or even good enough

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with LINQ.

PseudoCode:

```
dateList.Where(x => x.Month == 6).Max()
```

This gives you the latest date of june.

Make sure to use the right properties of your DateTime type instead of `*.Month`. You might also need to specify the `.Max()`, maybe with a `.Select(x => x.Day).Max()`.

Nevertheless: LINQ is the way to go. 
Hope it helps.

Comment: That won't return the end of month for the dates, it will return the maximum date for a single month. You should probably use GroupBy